# Warning Regarding the UITableviewcell

Tags: iphone

```
cell.text = [tableoptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

when i write this statement,I get warning like 'setText:' is deprecated.

how to remove this warning?????

Comment: Voting to close as exact duplicate of 1089676 and others

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [tableoptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The text property was deprecated and textLabel and detailedTextLabel were introduced. See [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/textLabel).